# Where to download specific java jdk/jre

Tags: java

I  want to download java version build 1.5.0_06-b05 which is Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 1.5.0_06-b05, mixed mode)

I went to this URL http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html#jdk-1.5.0_06-oth-JPR but could not find build 5.

Where can I download the same

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle archive link that you found is your best bet, and you are right they don't have build 5.  Unless you can find someone that happens to have that specific build sitting around then I think you are out of luck.

Since you are looking for such a specific build it make me think there is an ancient application that requires this.  If so the vendor for that application might be a good place to look for that specific JRE.

Answer (score 0):

The below link has worked for me. Probably you may need username and password to login to the oracle network.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html#jdk-1.5.0_06-oth-JPR